# Google Charts API - Column patterns and "TimeOfDay" data type

Tags: google-visualization, timeofday

I'm working with the Google Charts API to create a graph of a student's test-taking performance. On the X axis, the graph shows the days of the week. On the Y axis, the graph shows how long the student spent taking the exam. (The goal is for teachers to see if the student speeds up). However, I have a problem:

My data is in the timeofday format, and I'm providing values to the chart as time durations using the Google Charts [HH,MM,SS,MSEC] format. When the chart renders, the Y axis is printed as "HH:MM:SS". I'd really like to customize that because the seconds are pretty useless and it looks messier than I'd like.

The Charts API says you can specify a "pattern" for a column, and I've specified "HH:MM". However, that doesn't seem to take effect at all. Anybody have experience formatting timeofday in Google Charts and know how to do this?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Additionally, I'd also want to show the legend values in the custom format but haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 9):

The format is buried deep in the API documentation. (http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html). It is about quarter way down, it says:

> If the column type is 'timeofday', the value is an array of four
>   numbers: [hour, minute, second, milliseconds].

Comment: The OP has already mentioned that he is passing the time values in an array

Answer (score 3):

More than words can say: The followingURL is a full working version for Stockprices during the days, and can be found at 'http://www.harmfrielink.nl/Playgarden/GoogleCharts-Tut-07.html'
Since a complete listing can not be posted correctly I only give the important parts:

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {
     // Create the data table.
     var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     dataTable.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
     dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Price (Euro)');
     dataTable.addRows([
        [new Date(2014, 6, 2,  9,  0, 0, 0), 21.40],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 2, 11,  0, 0, 0), 21.39],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 2, 13,  0, 0, 0), 21.20],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 2, 15,  0, 0, 0), 21.22],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 2, 17,  0, 0, 0), 20.99],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 2, 17, 30, 0, 0), 21.03],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 3,  9,  0, 0, 0), 21.05],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 3, 11,  0, 0, 0), 21.07],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 3, 13,  0, 0, 0), 21.10],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 3, 15,  0, 0, 0), 21.08],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 3, 17,  0, 0, 0), 21.05],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 3, 17, 30, 0, 0), 21.00],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 4,  9,  0, 0, 0), 21.15],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 4, 11,  0, 0, 0), 21.17],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 4, 13,  0, 0, 0), 21.25],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 4, 15,  0, 0, 0), 21.32],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 4, 17,  0, 0, 0), 21.35],
        [new Date(2014, 6, 4, 17, 30, 0, 0), 21.37],
     ]);

     // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
     // var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

     var options = {
        title    : 'AEX Stock: Nationale Nederlanden (NN)',
        width    : 1400,
        height   : 540,
        legend   : 'true',
        pointSize: 5,
        vAxis: { title: 'Price (Euro)', maxValue: 21.50, minValue: 20.50 },
        hAxis: { title: 'Time of day (Hours:Minutes)', format: 'HH:mm', gridlines: {count:9} }
     };

     var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
        {prefix: '', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true});

     var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat(
        { prefix: 'Time: ', pattern: "dd MMM HH:mm", });

     formatDate.format(dataTable, 0);
     formatNumber.format(dataTable, 1);

     chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }  // drawChart

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
   <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
 </body>
```

The example will:

- Make a formatted hAxis with format HH:mm i.e. 18:00 for 6:00 PM.
- Formats the data in the graph (hover over the data-plots) with day and time and the stock price.
- Gives the graph gridlines.

I hope this example makes it clear how to handle the data in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

In chart the options object you could set the *vAxis* object with the field *format* and provide a string with the pattern you want to use here's an example:

```
new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  draw(data,
       {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
        width:600, height:400,
        vAxis: {title: "Year", format: "yy"},
        hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
  );
```

Look at the vAxis object.

For the string format you should look to http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime to build you the pattern you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hAxis.format or vAxis.format option. This allows you to specify a format string, where you use placeholder letters for different parts of your timeofday

To get rid of the seconds, you can set the format of the Y Axis like this:

```
  var options = {
    vAxis: { format: 'hh:mm' }
  };
```